# CSS Positioning Set or remove

Tags: css

I see on W3Schools the css position rule default option is static. My question is I use position:static; css rule in header,section and footer element If i not set this so I remove position rule from css elements then as well will be display as static or need to set to be default?

```
header,section,footer{position:static;}
```

or

> header,section,footer{noneed:static;}

Comment: Finding it difficult to work out what you are asking. Could you possibly re-word?

Comment: I truly have no clue what you're asking.

Comment: So need to set static option in css if i want the default static option or just do empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking about default element positioning rule. All `HTML` elements are by default `static` except `body`. So you can use `position:static` to any element you want to act as `static`. However if you do not mention this in your `css` it would not hurt either. As you know every elements are by default `static`. You need not to reset them (`header, section, footer` etc.).

But if you are using media-query, and you have set an element as `position: relative` or `position:absolute` or `position:fixed`, which, at some resolution should be `static`, then you need to reset it by using `position: static` at that particular resolution.